# Unable to get a specific page url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set `position: absolute` to `.navbar.navbar-fixed-top` only when the page url is `.../demo/` using jquery.

This is what I've done so far

HTML:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    some content here
  </nav>

  <div class="commenting-demo">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location == "/demo/") {
    $(".navbar.navbar-fixed-top").css({"position": "absolute"});
  }
});
```

I use `window.location = "/demo/"` to redirect the user to this page when an event occurs and it worked, but I don't understand why the above condition does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `indexOf()` or `substring()` methods you can. But it's not recommended. The best way you can do is mark the page with a classname or an id or a custom attribute like this:

```
<body class="demo-page">
```

And then

```
if($('body').hasClass('demo-page')) {
      // your stuff only in demo-page
}
```

Comment: Already tried this because I have a class `commenting-demo` but it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I have a div with `commenting-demo` class inside of `body` tag

Comment: Seems like it's working with `if($('body .commenting-demo').length > 0)` , is this expression a good way to implement this?

Comment: if the expression works , your classname is not applied to the body, it's applied to a child element of the body. It's because `hasClass()`doesn't works. Copy your html and I tell you how to make it

Comment: Oh, I read carefully now and I understand, you have a div with this class. Yes, you can make it with the `length` property. `if($('.commenting-demo').length > 0)) { .... }`

Comment: Searching the whole of the dom for a class vs parsing the URL is not a good way to do this imho

Comment: Updated my question. I need to check if `body` has a `div` with `.commenting-demo` or `forums-demo` classes ... can I use `if($('body .commenting-demo, .forums-demo').length > 0)` for this?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney the problem checking an string in the URL is not the resources that browser needs, it's full of problems with string comparison for example. However, my recommendation is adding the class in the  `body`or in the `html`.

Comment: Can't add a class to neither `body` or `html` tags because these are rendered in all pages

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude my last question.... can I add `.forums-demo` in the `if` condition? Please see the above comment, I want to know if this is a correct sintax :). Thanks a lot !

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I get that, but the OP was specific about the URL, so checking the DOM vs parsing the URL is not the best option in this case

Comment: @PavelValeriu yes, you can. By comma separated, you can add all classes you need. DarrenSweeney: I only offer another solution less dangerous. If the URL changes a dot the parser will be different and you need to update. Parsing URLs with string comparison is dangerous and causes multiple and different issues in the life of the application.

Comment: @PavelValeriu you can make the if with the OR logical operator like this `if($('.commenting-demo').length > 0 || $('.forums-demo').length > 0)) { .... } `

Comment: Yes, but this is not the same as the comma separator?

Comment: not the same, but with your purpose you can use both of them. Only choose what you think that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what the last section of the url is between the last two `/.../` then try this:

```
url = 'http://myfabsite.com/demo/';

/* get last part of url between last two / ... / */
var pageUrlSection = url.split('/').slice(-2)[0]; 

alert(pageUrlSection); // alerts "demo"
```

So in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = window.location.href; // get the url
  var pageUrlSection = url.split('/').slice(-2)[0];
  if(pageUrlSection  == "demo") {
    $(".navbar.navbar-fixed-top").css({"position": "absolute"});
  }
});
```